# case insensitive fredhopper claims?

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

All fredhopper claims are case sensitive, is there any way to make them case insensitive.

My Triggers-type.xml is having triggers like

```
 <value>Dispenser</value>
```

so if I pass claim as **dispenser**, promotion are not getting returned.

How to configure fredhopper to sent promotion when claims are sent in any case, so a claim with vlaue dispenser , Dispenser, dIspenser should return promotion.

My own solution is to make everything in lowercase but in that case SmartTarget UI will also display triggers in lower case. I want to display trigger in SmartTarget UI as "Dispenser" only and want fredhooper to return promotion when claims are passed in any case.

Comment: I second your preference for capitalization in SmartTarget. Based on Peter's response, it looks like you'll have to stick to a single capitilization convention, but this could be useful as an [SDL Tridion Idea](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/). Out of curiosity, is the case-sensitivity issue coming up in querystring parameters or in code?

Comment: Alvin, Trigger may come in any case in querystring thats why I posted this question. For making all query sting parameters in lower case I user Url Rewrite module. But If I make triggers too in lowercase then SmratTarget UI will also display triggers in lower case. As per solution by Peter, looks like we need to make everything in small.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already figured out, Fredhopper is case-sensitive so you will have to ensure that you use the same casing every time. I am not aware of any setting that changes that.

It sounds like you should just stick to Pascal case. That's not really any harder than making it always lowercase or uppercase.